# Not getting data by using ngDrive module by pinoyyid

Tags: google-drive-api

```
<html> 
<body ng-app="MyApp">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <li ng-repeat="file in vm.filesArray">{{file.title}}</li>
</div>   
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/auth.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script src="../bower_components/ngDrive/build/module.js"></script>    
<script>

    var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngm.ngDrive']);  
    angular.module('ngm.ngDrive')
            .provider('OauthService', ngDrive.Config)
            .config(function (OauthServiceProvider) {
                OauthServiceProvider.setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file');
                OauthServiceProvider.setClientID('10503878599-98uqrqmgq2f3kc1sbr13l6rma20ue7l0.apps.googleusercontent.com');

            });
    var MainCtrl = (function () {           
        function MainCtrl(DriveService) {          
            this.filesArray = DriveService.files.list({
                q: 'trashed = false',
                maxResults: 10,
                fields: 'items/title'
            }, true).data;             
        }          
        MainCtrl.$inject = ['DriveService'];
        return MainCtrl;
    })();
    angular.module('MyApp').controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using ngDrive by pinoyyid . 
This is my index.html .
I have provided a valid client ID. 
It returns an empty array in files array. 
Please suggest any solution